# YouTube v3 Authentication and Google+

Tags: php, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, google-plus, youtube-data-api

I'd like to implement YouTube OAuth 2.0 on my application. I'd also like the user to have access to Google+ features at the same time.

Can someone (maybe even someone from the YouTube API team) tell me if I am reading the content on this link correctly?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication

It looks like if I implement one of the recommended client libraries (thinking of implementing the one called "Google APIs Client Library for PHP"), the user will also have access to Google+ social network features.

Is this correct? I want to make sure I'm seeing this right before I go through the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the PHP client library supports all of Google's REST APIs including YouTube and Google+. Make sure you get the latest one and keep it updated.